# Displaying text in lwjgl in java without using slick

Tags: java, text, lwjgl

I am trying to display some text in lwjgl in java **but I dont want to use slick library**, do you know if there is any other way to show some text in java using lwjgl ? If so, which external libraries I need to import ??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible. Either draw it pixel by pixel or use a library. You'll only need [slick-util](http://slick.ninjacave.com/slick-util.jar) for drawing text, so it shouldn't be a problem. You can find the javadocs [here](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc-util/).

Comment: Unfortunately I have problem working with slick, when I am trying to use slick I will have only a rectangle filled by a color instead of the text ... this is really annoying i search a lot but there is no optimum answer for that.

Comment: Well, did you enable GL_TEXTURE_2D beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way I know is to create a java awt image and draw the text on it (using awt) and then pass it to opengl. So, just create a BufferedImage, get its graphics context and write on it using the methods in that. Shouldn't be too hard.